# Rendering LaTeX to an image

Tags: php, c, latex, tex

I have read lots of questions and answers here but I haven't found a clear Question/Answer.

I need to create a really simple webpage which allows users to enter LaTeX and generate a PNG (or other lightweight image format). The webpage contains only a `textarea` and a `submit button` and it produces a link like "http://www.example.com/generated-images/cnl344l4jcxlj.png" with the image.

**INPUT**: already-written latex like

```
f(x)=\displaystyle\int_{-\infty}^x e^{-t^2}dt
```

**OUTPUT**: Link to the generated PNG or GIF image

[image: http://rinconmatematico.com/latexrender/pictures/35800007a15a3f0e39006dc63f04f1b5.gif]

The processing of the latex code and the generation of the image should happen in the server-side (so no JavaScript)

I'd like to do this in PHP (which I'm pretty good at), but if there are simple-enough libraries I could give it a shot in Perl.

A straightforward implementation in pure C could also work. A program which `scanf`s the input latex code and `printf`s "image generated at c:/program/image00000000001.gif"

Any free/opensource libraries that do any of this? Any advice in how to proceed? Any special concerns?

http://rinconmatematico.com/latexrender/pictures/35800007a15a3f0e39006dc63f04f1b5.gif

Comment: Have you checked google? Simple shell script from http://www.nought.de/tex2im.php worked for me.

Comment: Perhaps this helps: [TeX to image over command line](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34054/tex-to-image-over-command-line/34058#34058)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try:

- [TeX2PNG](http://xyne.archlinux.ca/projects/tex2png/) - generate png image for given equation
- [MathJax](http://www.mathjax.org/) - JavaScript library that find and render math equations in HTML
- [KaTeX](https://github.com/Khan/KaTeX) - lighter and a little bit less capable alternative to MathJax

Comment: Wish there would be a pure C/C++ solution that doesn't require a 100MB package (a running webbrowser or a full LaTex installation + perl + ghostscript).

Answer (score 4):

Look at dvipng. I wouldn't write a wrapper over it in C but in a scripting language.

Answer (score 2):

If it's not a high-traffic website, you can try online rendering with sites like the [Online LaTeX Equation Editor](http://www.codecogs.com/latex/eqneditor.php). In particular, this site allows you to put LaTaX directly into the URL like the following:

[image: \sum_k a_k]

The URL being: [http://latex.codecogs.com/gif.latex?\sum_k%20a_k](http://latex.codecogs.com/gif.latex?%5Csum_k%20a_k)

Comment: Nice but if formulas are long, the rendering is put on multilines